# Javascript not working on google chrome and smartphone browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, cross-browser

I am working on a ASP.NET/C# Web Application
I have a check box. and I want that check box to simulate a button click when checked/unchecked

I used javascript to do it

```
<input id="filtercheck" runat="server" type="checkbox" value="Filter" onclick="document.getElementById('Button1').click();"/>
```

Button1 is a normal button

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

So when I click on the checkbox, it is the same as if I clicked on the Button1.

Everything works fine on firefox and internet explorer. but this is not working on Google Chrome and smartphone browsers

How can I fix this problem?

in addition there are some few other javascript and Jquery scripts that are working on internet explorer and firefox but not on Google Chrome and smartphone browsers.

What can I do to make sure my website is fully compatible on all browsers?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: jQuery is very good at cross browser compatibility. Use jQuery to wire up event handlers and you'll likely have better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Yep, it was this first thing. Chrome was choking on the linkButton and not rendering it as expected.

I was going to ask. Is that ID the same as the HTML id attribute? How does an asp "LinkButton" render as HTML?

Edit: I'll leave the rest here in case it's helpful to anyone else having trouble with asp.net shenanigans.

Have you validated your HTML. What you're doing isn't particularly crazy. HTML breakage might be the cause.

Also, try just firing that function once through other means in Chrome.

One thing that's helpful though. Get your JavaScript off the page and put it in a linked file. Do NOT let any Microsoft product tell you anything about making js easier by doing it their way. The best thing they ever did was .net MVC which just gets the hell out of your way.

edit: Wait. Are you using webforms? That might be your problem. In that case you might have to fire focus and then click at the stupid thing. Some MS engineers safeguard against people finding an easy way to daisy-chain around their tomfoolery. I waded through a lot of horrendous JS to figure that one out a while back.

Comment: your first question gave me the answer. Apparently there was an error rendering the asp "LinkButton" in google chrome. I changed the "LinkButton" to a simple "Button" and it worked. Thanks. (Add this info to your answer and I will accept it as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need Button1 ClientID?

```
document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID %>').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully compatible on all browsers?  The short answer? `No fancy stuff.`

A slightly longer answer is just to do what is allowed by the standards set forth by w3c and hope all browsers are compliant.  They never will be 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, I'd recommend that you use the [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method

**EDIT**: as Koste pointed out, you might also want to use the ClientID instead of the actual id.